# Run Oracle 12c on Kubernetes

Tags: oracle, kubernetes, oracle12c

I am trying to run Oracle 12c on Kubernetes.
When I start it as docker container the FIRST TIME I have to wait until it configures.
It configures successfully and pass scripts in my `configDBora.sh` that I'd added.

BUT If I want to login as user that I created I couldn't do that. I have to restart the container at LEAST ONCE.

How can I do that in Kubernetes? There is no stop command. I also tried changing replicas to 0 of my deployment but it deletes existing pod.

What script can I add to `configDBora.sh` or do something else to restart a container with oracle on kubernetes?

The end of the script in `configDBora.sh` is:

```
#A lot of scipt here
...
echo "$DB_PDB = \
  (DESCRIPTION = \
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 0.0.0.0)(PORT = 1521)) \
    (CONNECT_DATA = \
      (SERVER = DEDICATED) \
      (SERVICE_NAME = $DB_PDB.$DB_DOMAIN) \
    ) \
  ) \
" >> $TNS_ORA

# start listener
lsnrctl start

# clean
unset DB_PASSWD
history -w
history -c

echo ""
echo "DONE!"

# end
```

Deployment oracle:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\kubernetes-kompose\tools\kompose.exe convert
    kompose.version: 1.26.0 (40646f47)
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: oracle
  name: oracle
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      io.kompose.service: oracle
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        kompose.cmd: C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\kubernetes-kompose\tools\kompose.exe convert
        kompose.version: 1.26.0 (40646f47)
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        io.kompose.service: oracle
    spec:
      containers:
        - env:
            - name: ORACLE_MEM
              value: "2000"
            - name: ORACLE_PDB
              value: ORCLPDB
            - name: ORACLE_PWD
              value: Admin123
            - name: ORACLE_SID
              value: ORCLCDB
          image: maxprimeaery/oracle-12c-base:5.0
          name: oracle
          ports:
            - containerPort: 1521
#          resources:
#            limits:
#              memory: "1073741824"
      restartPolicy: Always
status: {}
```

Service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\kubernetes-kompose\tools\kompose.exe convert
    kompose.version: 1.26.0 (40646f47)
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: oracle
  name: oracle
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - name: "1521"
      port: 1521
      targetPort: 1521
  selector:
    io.kompose.service: oracle
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use and how exactly did you set up your cluster? Could you please also provide more details on your pod configuration?

Comment: @anarxz added more info to my question

Comment: @anarxz Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"23", GitVersion:"v1.23.0", GitCommit:"ab69524f795c42094a6630298ff53f3c3ebab7f4", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-
12-07T18:16:20Z", GoVersion:"go1.17.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"windows/amd64"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only problem was 12c version of Oracle.

I moved my DB to Oracle 19c Enterprise Edition and my problem was solved. With Oracle 19c I don't need to restart pod with oracle but I need more ram and rom memory for it.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can try to restart your deployment:

```
kubectl rollout restart deployment <deployment_name>
```

It will perform shutdown and restart of the container without interruptions to the service.
Please check [What is Kubectl Rollout Restart?](https://linuxhint.com/kubectl-rollout-restart/) for more information about this method.

**Edit:** It is the way Kubernetes is supposed to  work -  by handling automatic replacement of the pod with the new one as soon as the container is restarted. It is not common to modify the pod inside, but you can try to perform force reboot of the container inside of particular pod by applying such command:

```
kubectl exec -it <pod_name> -c <container_name> -- /sbin/reboot
```

Or it can be force termination of the container, depending on your container settings:

```
kubectl exec -it <pod_name> -c <container_name> -- /bin/sh -c "kill 1"
```

Once container is terminated, it will be restarted after few seconds in the same pod.

Comment: But this command will delete a pod and start to configure oracle from zero.

Comment: @MaxPrime I've edited the answer to provide one more solution, please check.

Comment: thank you for the answer but I don't want to touch Oracle 12c anymore (yet). Oracle 19c works as it should without any restarts.